# How to calculate rdlc tablix rows sum and rows count in textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, report, rdlc

**I have tablix named tablix2 and have 3 columns ,I want to calculate rows sum and count in 2 textboxes out of the tablix scope, I try this expression.**

```
=RowNumber("Tablix2")
```

And

```
=CountRows("Tablix2")
```

And

```
=Count(Fields!ID.Value,"Tablix2")
```

## Its always show me this error message:

**The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox7’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a scope name which is valid. If you're outside of the tablix then you should use dataset scope probably.

Try something like

`=Count(Fields!ID.Value,"DatasetName")` or

`=Sum(Fields!ID.Value,"DatasetName")`

Comment: Thank you for answer but I need to perform the aggregate methods on tablix (tables) , not DataSet if you know any information i'll be thankful .

Comment: You can't use a scope that you're outside of (as the error message says).

Comment: Yeah I see , I solve it by using stored procedure with parameters in SqlDataSource before the report opened and make the Count through Dataset .Thanks fore helping .

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the tablix on the last row in the group (you have to do this in the "handle" area to the far left because you get a different right click menu if you click in the row area), then choose "Insert Row" and "Outside Group Below."  Merge cells as necessary and drag a textbox into the one you want to put the value.  Then put =Count(Fields!ID.Value) for the expression inside the textbox to get the group count, for example.

This worked for me, but I agree it is far from intuitive and doesn't appear to be documented well anywhere for what should be such a basic feature in a reportwriter.

Comment: This worked for me, however I used "Inside Group Below" to count the items that applied to the group.

Answer (score 0):

I created a report footer and added this code to a textbox below. DataSet1 is the name of the dataset in the report (case-sensitive). Fields doesn't change. Sym is the name of the column in the details of the report,

=Count(Fields!Sym.Value,"DataSet1").